# Resetting all saved WiFi connections on Android with CM12

Tags: android, wifimanager, cyanogenmod

I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy S4 with CyanogenMod 12.0 on it.

I had a lot of Wifi connections, about 100, which I restored with Titanium Backup, when I installed CM12.
Then I had the effect, that when entering the area of a known Wifi, the phone didn't connect to this Wifi. Only when I disabled mobile data, the phone connected to the Wifi, after this I could reenable the mobile data and the wifi-connection would now stay connected.
So I deleted in the wifi-manager's list all of them and added the important ones one by one, but the problem persists.
Now I think maybe if I reset the Wifi completely and restore a few connections manually it could work again, but I don't know how to reset Wifi.
It is not done by deleting all Wifi-networks in the manager's list, this didn't help.

How can I reset all Wifi settings to factory default, without resetting the phone to factory, which I absolutely don't want to do?
As I have root, there must be some files or database which I had to delete, but which?
In the settings app list (all apps) I don't find the Wifi-Manager app. 
Which app and where is it?

Thank.s

frank

Comment: I have now updated to CM 12.1 and the problem doesn't exist here anymore. So the question is not anymore interesting.